# Pandas Dataframe: Accessing element which is a subelement in a list which is in a cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

A column in my dataframe consists of lists with one list being in one cell. How do I access an element inside that list without any reassignment?
A snippet in the list:
[Need to access 00:00:00 itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAUw9.png)

Edit: Trying to extract only the time part from the series. 
[Snippet from where the list is being created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRCWO.png)
Split it like a string into 2 halves and picked only the second in a list. Can't reference the time directly from the list while iterating through the dataframe. 
Didn't understand why this gives an error. I do understand index out of range, but any way to get around without reassignment.
List from where time is to be picked:
[Time list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkVnd.png)
On trying direct manipulation as in the for extracting time:
[Error that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkIkz.png)
Is reassignment the only way around? Though even that doesn't seem to work in the loop 
**Also is the looping correct for iterrows?**

Comment: Please provide some sample data. What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Based on your image, does `df['MDEndTime'][1][0]` not work?

Comment: Doesn't work in the loop. Gives out of range